# How to remove every pattern match and write it in new file

Tags: sed, regular-expression

So i have a long string that have no blanks and i want to remove every time the pattern match.
This is how the string looks like:

```
bdy11<entryunit="phoenix"><name>costperdps</name><value>27.75</value></entry><entryunit="phoenix"><name>damage</name><value>5</value></entry><entrbdy623yunit="phoenix"><name>dps</name><value>9.01</value></entry><entryunit="phoenix"><name>dpsplusbonus</name><value>18.02</value></entry><entryunit="phoenix"><name>dpsplusupgbonus</name><value>23.42</value></entry><entryunit="phoenix"><name>dpsplusupgrades</name><value>14.41</value></entry><entryunit="phoenix"><name>range</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="phoenix"><name>targets</name><value>air</value></entry><entryunit="phoenix"><name>upgrade</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit=bdy624"phoenix"><name>upgrade_damage</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>attack</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>bonus_damage</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>bonus_type</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>cooldown</name><value>1.25</value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>costperdps</name><value>9.38</value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>damage</name><value>20</value><bdy625/entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>dps</name><value>16.00</value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>dpsplusbonus</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>dpsplusupgbonus</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>dpsplusupgrades</name><value>16.00</value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>range</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>targets</name><value>both</value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>upgrbdy626ade</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="photoncannon"><name>upgrade_damage</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>attack</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>bonus_damage</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>bonus_type</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>cooldown</name><value>1.50</value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>costperdps</name><value>15.00</value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>damage</name><value>5</valubdy627e></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>dps</name><value>3.33</value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>dpsplusbonus</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>dpsplusupgbonus</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>dpsplusupgrades</name><value>3.33</value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>range</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>targets</name><value>ground</value></entry><entryunit="probe"><name>upgrade</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="probe">bdy628<name>upgrade_damage</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>attack</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>bonus_damage</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>bonus_type</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>cooldown</name><value>1.00</value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>costperdps</name><value>25.00</value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>damage</name><value>6</value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>dps</name><value>6bdy629.00</value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>dpsplusbonus</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>dpsplusupgbonus</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>dpsplusupgrades</name><value>9.00</value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>range</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>targets</name><value>both</value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>upgrade</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="sentry"><name>upgrade_damage</name><value></value></entrbdy630y><entryunit="stalker"><name>attack</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>bonus_damage</name><value>4</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>bonus_type</name><value>armored</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>cooldown</name><value>1.44</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>costperdps</name><value>25.20</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>damage</name><value>10</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>dps</name><value>6.94</value></entry><entryunit="bdy631stalker"><name>dpsplusbonus</name><value>9.72</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>dpsplusupgbonus</name><value>11.81</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>dpsplusupgrades</name><value>9.03</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>range</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>targets</name><value>both</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>upgrade</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="stalker"><name>upgrade_damage</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="vbdy632oidray"><name>attack</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>bonus_damage</name><value>4</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>bonus_type</name><value>armored</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>cooldown</name><value>.60</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>costperdps</name><value>35.00</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>damage</name><value>6</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>dps</name><value>10.00</value></entry><entryunit="voidray">bdy633<name>dpsplusbonus</name><value>16.67</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>dpsplusupgbonus</name><value>21.67</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>dpsplusupgrades</name><value>15.00</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>range</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>targets</name><value>both</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>upgrade</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="voidray"><name>upgrade_damage</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="vobdy634idraycharged"><name>attack</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>bonus_damage</name><value>8</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>bonus_type</name><value>armored</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>cooldown</name><value>.60</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>costperdps</name><value>26.25</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>damage</name><value>8</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>dps</nbdy635ame><value>13.33</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>dpsplusbonus</name><value>26.67</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>dpsplusupgbonus</name><value>36.67</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>dpsplusupgrades</name><value>18.33</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>range</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>targets</name><value>both</value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>upgrade</name><value>1<bdy636/value></entry><entryunit="voidraycharged"><name>upgrade_damage</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>attack</name><value>2</value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>bonus_damage</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>bonus_type</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>cooldown</name><value>1.20</value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>costperdps</name><value>7.50</value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>damage</name><value>8</value></entrybdy637><entryunit="zealot"><name>dps</name><value>13.33</value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>dpsplusbonus</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>dpsplusupgbonus</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>dpsplusupgrades</name><value>18.33</value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>range</name><value></value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>targets</name><value>ground</value></entry><entryunit="zealot"><name>upgrade</name><value>1</value></entry><entryunit="zealotbdy638"><name>upgrade_damage</name><value></value></entry></record>trl000000204000001410
```

I want to remove every time there is bdy followed by 2 digits and bdy followed by 3 digits. So far I tried to use sed with regular expression but I believe that there is a mistake in the regular expression

```
sed 's/(.*bdy\d\d)//g; s/(.*bdy\d\d\d)//g' newTarget
```

I plan to use pipe to transform the text with

```
sed -e "
  s|<tag>|\n&|
  s/.*\n//
  s|</tag>|&\n|
  /\n/P;D
" newTarget > newTarget2
```

To get each tag on new line so its easier to extract the data between the tags but before i do that i need to remove bdy followed by the numbers because occurs in between tags.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to transform your string into valid XML.  You will not only need to remove the `bdy` strings but also need to fix the `entry` tag and its `unit` attribute (currently written together as `entryunit`), add the missing `<record>` start tag at the start and remove the `trl` string at the very end.

You may do this with `echo` and `sed`, and then reformat it for readability using `xmlstarlet`:

```bsh
{
    echo '<record>'
    sed -e 's/bdy[0-9]\{2,3\}//g' \
        -e 's/entryunit/entry unit/g' \
        -e 's/trl[0-9]*$//' file
} | xmlstarlet fo
```

Or, on a single line,

```bsh
{ echo '<record>'; sed -e 's/bdy[0-9]\{2,3\}//g' -e 's/entryunit/entry unit/g' -e 's/trl[0-9]*$//' file; } | xmlstarlet fo
```

The `xmlstarlet` bit is only necessary if you want to reformat the document nicely.  Without reformatting, an XML parser would still be able to read it without issue.

The `sed` command first deletes all the `bdy` strings.  We match one or two digits after the substring `bdy` using `[0-9]\{2,3\}`, which means "two or three digits between 0 and 9".

The `entryunit` string is corrected into `entry unit` using a straightforward substitution.

We delete the `trl` string and the trailing string of digits with the last substitution.

This, with `xmlstarlet` reformatting, should give you output looking like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<record>
  <entry unit="phoenix">
    <name>costperdps</name>
    <value>27.75</value>
  </entry>
  <entry unit="phoenix">
    <name>damage</name>
    <value>5</value>
  </entry>

[...]

  <entry unit="zealot">
    <name>upgrade</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </entry>
  <entry unit="zealot">
    <name>upgrade_damage</name>
    <value/>
  </entry>
</record>
```

Regardless of whether you reformat the resulting XML document with `xmlstarlet` or not later, you may extract data using the tool like so:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//entry[@unit="photoncannon" and name="cooldown"]/value' -nl file
```

The above outputs the value of the `value` node belonging to the `entry` whose `unit` attribute is `photoncannon` and whose `name` child node's value is `cooldown`.  In other words, it gets the cool-down value for the photon cannon.

With parameters taken from shell variables:

```bsh
unit=photoncannon
name=cooldown
xmlstrlet sel -t \
    --var unit="'$unit'" \
    --var name="'$name'" \
    -v '//entry[@unit=$unit and name=$name]/value' -nl file
```

(Note the specific quoting used; the internal variables `$unit` and `$name` must contain XML-encoded strings, which means they need to have explicit quotes added.)

You could obviously use any other XML parser to do the same thing.  The following uses `xq` (from [here](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/)), which is an XML parser sitting on top of `jq`, the JSON parser, which means it first translates your XML document into JSON, and then calls `jq` to parse the resulting data:

```bsh
unit=photoncannon
name=cooldown
xq -r \
    --arg unit "$unit" \
    --arg name "$name" \
    '.record.entry[] | select(."@unit" == $unit and .name == $name).value' file
```

Comment: Tanks mate, its what i needed to do. But without xmlstartlet . I need to use the digits after  the bdy since this whole thing will be used as load ready file for SQL . First digit is the XML_ID , rest of the digits are SEGMENT_ID so i will need to save everything that is removed in another file and afterwards combine the data from both files to make make it looks like : XML_ID SEGMENT_ID eUnit name value -> 1,1,phoenix,costperdps,27.75
for each <entry unit ....>.......</entry>